# If `redux` is not in package.json or package-lock.json or node_modules, how come importing anything from 'redux' still works?

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, node-modules

I have a line in my project:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```

but `package.json` doesn't have `redux` (it only has `react-redux`). And the same is true in `package-lock.json` and the folder `node_modules`.

Further it is not installed globally, since if I do

```
npm list -g redux
```

it shows it is not installed:

```
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)
```

So how come we can still import things from `redux`?

**P.S. I double checked** http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js and it listed `redux` as `"../../../node_modules/redux/..."` and `react-redux` as  `"./node_modules/react-redux/...` So I double check 2 levels up my project, and inside of my home directory, there is a `node_modules` folder... so it looks like it could "go up" to look for node_modules?  Could it be dangerous that way? But on the other hand, could it be useful if we want to develop several experimental React app, without repeating the same node_modules with each one about 200MB?

Comment: I think if you install with yarn the yarn.lock will have redux and will tell you where it's located.

Comment: @HMR if I do `yarn install`, then my `yarn.lock` also only has `react-redux@^7.2.0` but not `redux`

Answer (score -1):

Because it's [a peer dependency of `react-redux`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/package.json) and **it does** appear in `node_modules/redux/index` (in the project folder) as peer dependencies must be installed in order to use the relevant package.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "redux": "^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0-0"
}
```

Comment: but in my `node_modules` there is no `redux`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not looking in the right place, without any producible example/screenshots can't help you.

Comment: `$  ls node_modules/redux
ls: node_modules/redux: No such file or directory`

Comment: Why would it be in the global scope? It located in `node_modules` in your project directory as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Also, I checked my answer on my own project

Comment: i am doing `ls` in my project

Comment: It is not really helping if you don't give additional information and a **producible example**

Comment: I found out something new and put it in my P.S.

Comment: Again, you not showing the full picture, we can't know how you installed your project and how it structured, from your update it seems you got nested projects and it takes `redux` from another inner repository, which looks like kind of optimization and won't cause any harm as in production it will be installed in the same repository.

Comment: I don't know why you keep on accusing. I am not a lawyer coming up to present a case. I merely see something happening and hope to know if somebody had that problem before and readily know what happened by past experience